# Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed and Please update the following components: Motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have migrated react-dom version to 16.9.0+. Since then I am getting this warning.
I have tried to resolve it by running `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in my source folder and couple of other trails but all in vain.
**Here in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/maddinaprudhvi/animatedMenuIcon)(https://codesandbox.io/s/github/maddinaprudhvi/animatedMenuIcon) sandbox I tried to replicate my warning.**

Warning that I have got :

> react-dom.development.js:12357 Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has
>   been renamed, and is not recommended for use.
>
> - Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
> - If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static
>     getDerivedStateFromProps.
> - Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the
>     UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their
>     new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in
>     your project source folder.
>
> Please update the following components: Motion

My questions are:

> How can i get rid of this warning?

Why is this happening just after migrating my react-dom to 16.9.0 and further versions there after?

> Even after running `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in
>   source folder why this depricated lifecycle is not renamed to UNSAFE_lifecycle-name and why Motion Component is not updating?

Thank you in advance for the help and for spending your time.

Comment: There's no `componentWillReceiveProps` in your sandbox.. How are you planning to use it? You may wanna look into `react hooks` that's an update of react classes.. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-framework-yold3)'s a working sandbox from yours one, but in hooks.

Comment: @leverglowh I have used Motion component from react-motion. may be that one will be using componentWillRecieveProps. Anyway i dont know exactly what's happening under the hood that's why i have raised question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a issue with `react-motion` https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion/issues/569, but its not actively maintained and should be fixed on the library front.

> If your app runs, it'll be fine. Warnings from
>   react-dom.development.js won't appear in production.

Comment: Gone through that issue you shared, seems still unresolved. I haven't gone to production yet but in pipeline tests same warning is appearing (componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed) .